# Getting fetch returns more than requested number of rows error SQL HANA SAP

Tags: sql, syntax

Hello can you please help me fix this query :

```
SELECT T1."Price" into pght FROM ITM1 T1 WHERE T1."PriceList" = '1';

UPDATE "ITM1"
    SET ITM1."Factor" = T2."U_COEFFICIENT" , ITM1."Price" = T2."U_COEFFICIENT" * pght
    FROM ITM1
    INNER JOIN OITM T0 ON T0."ItemCode" = ITM1."ItemCode"
    INNER JOIN OMRC T1 ON T1."FirmCode" = T0."FirmCode"
    INNER JOIN "@PR_MARQUES_ASSOCIE" T2 ON T1."FirmName" = T2."U_MARQUES"
    WHERE T2."U_MARQUES" = 'ROCHAS' AND T2."Code" = '01' 
      AND ITM1."PriceList" = '2' AND T1."FirmName" = 'ROCHAS';
```

This is the error I get:

> Getting fetch returns more than requested number of rows error

Actually my goal is to update the column `ITM1."Price" where ITM1."PriceList" = '2'`  with the price Value where the `"PriceList" = '1' * factor`

For example:

```
ITM1."Price" and "PriceList" = '1' = 40 $ 
ITM1."Factor" = T2."U_COEFFICIENT" = 4
```

Then

```
ITM1."Price" and "PriceList" = '2' = 160 $
```

I tried the above query (in the body) and I think it's not correct.

UPDATE :
The message returned is the one in the title : 'Getting fetch returns more than requested number of rows error' .
The lookup need to take account the item from ITM1 .
It should take the price list = '1' which represent the 'purchase price' and multiplie with the factor .
"U_COEFFICIENT" is used in another table to manipulate and update the column "Factor" from table ITM1

[Exemple in Excel Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uS1U7.png)
[Exemple in Excel Format 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tm2bW.png)

Comment: This question needs a bit more work: what doesn't work as expected? Is an error message returned? Can just *any* `PRICE` from `ITM1` matching `"Pricelist"=1` be used or does this lookup have to take into account which item(?) from `ITM1` the new price should be assigned to?

Comment: Hello Lars Br , thanks for your comment . The message returned is the one in the title : 'Getting fetch returns more than requested number of rows error' . Indeed the lookup need to take account the item from ITM1 . It should take the price list = '1' which represent the 'purchase price' and multiplie with the factor . So for ex : Item A Pricelist 1 Prices = 30 , factor 2 ,  then Item A PriceList 2 = 60

Comment: Please actualize the question, don't add details in the comments. I did it for you. I am also confused the way it's presented. Why not showing input data and expected result as tables in tabular format, as usual? Also you are talking about "Factor" as input but not as output, although your query shows the opposite (only "U_COEFFICIENT" is in the input), so difficult to understand...

Comment: Hi , i edited the main question and added exemple in tabular format . Hope it can help understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is caused by this statement:

```sql
SELECT T1."Price" INTO pght FROM ITM1 T1 WHERE T1."PriceList" = '1';
```

in *combination* with the data in table `ITM1`.
There are more than a single record in `ITM1` that match the condition.

`SELECT INTO` requires a scalar - that is a single value - to be returned by the SELECT statement. If there are more (or no values at all) an error message is returned.

To avoid this error, there are a few options:

- make the filter conditions so specific that only a single record gets returned.
- use an aggregation, e.g. `MAX(T1."Price")` to return only a single value.
- make sure that the *data* in the table does not have multiple records for the filter condition.

Based on the column and table names I am *guessing* that the purpose for this query is to update the price of items in table `ITM1` with `"Pricelist"=2` with the value for the *same* item with `"Pricelist=1"` multiplied by some factor.
If that is indeed the case, a correlated subquery or a join would be a possible solution approaches.

Here is an example of how an outer join could work:

```sql
UPDATE "ITM1"
    SET ITM1."Factor" = T2."U_COEFFICIENT" 
      , ITM1."Price" = T2."U_COEFFICIENT" * COALESCE(ITM_P1."Price", 1.0)
    FROM ITM1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ITM1 ITM_P1
       ON ITM1."ItemCode" = ITM_P1."ItemCode"
       AND ITM1."PriceList" = '2'
       AND ITM_P1."PriceList" = '1'
    INNER JOIN OITM T0 
       ON T0."ItemCode" = ITM1."ItemCode"
    INNER JOIN OMRC T1 
       ON T1."FirmCode" = T0."FirmCode"
    INNER JOIN "@PR_MARQUES_ASSOCIE" T2 
       ON T1."FirmName" = T2."U_MARQUES"
    WHERE 
       T2."U_MARQUES" = 'ROCHAS' 
       AND T2."Code" = '01' 
       AND ITM1."PriceList" = '2' 
       AND T1."FirmName" = 'ROCHAS';
```

Note how `ITM1` is outer joined with itself - an outer join to allow for cases, where an item does not have a record with `"PriceList"=1`. For those non-matches a `NULL` will be returned and the `COALESCE()` function ensures that in those cases, the item price will be multiplied with 1.0.

Comment: Thanks , it is exactly what i was looking for and it's working !! Also thanks for the knowledge and tips :)